# How do I cache credentials on Android using Google Identity Toolkit?

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

The [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart) provides an activity that calls startSignIn every time. After first Google sign in this is a simple one click account picker, but I'd like to avoid sign in completely. There is a [note](https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-android/blob/master/tutorial/src/com/google/identitytoolkit/demo/GitkitDemo.java#L64) about creating a session, but is there an example of a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).